# What is the maximum recommended number of rows that a SQL 2008 R2 standalone server should store in a single table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, performance, large-data-volumes

I'm designing my DB for functionality and performance for realtime AJAX web applications, and I don't currently have the resources to add DB server redundancy or load-balancing.

Unfortunately, I have a table in my DB that could potentially end up storing hundreds of millions of rows, and will need to read and write quickly to prevent lagging the web-interface.

Most, if not all, of the columns in this table are individually indexed, and I'd love to know if there are other ways to ease the burden on the server when running querys on large tables. But is there eventually a cap for the size (in rows *or* GB) of a table before a single unclustered SQL server starts to choke?

My DB only has a dozen tables, with maybe a couple dozen foriegn key relationships. None of my tables have more than 8 or so columns, and only one or two of these tables will end up storing a large number of rows. Hopefully the simplicity of my DB will make up for the massive amounts of data in these couple tables ...

Comment: It all depends on your access patterns. For example, if you do table scans then it matters a lot more than if you just do index lookups.

Comment: @Gabe: For the most part I will just be doing index lookups, so that's good news ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rows are limited strictly by the amount of disk space you have available.  We have SQL Servers with hundreds of millions of rows of data in them.  Of course, those servers are rather large.

In order to keep the web interface snappy you will need to think about how you access that data.

One example is to stay away from any type of aggregate queries which require processing large swaths of data.  Things like SUM() can be a killer depending on how much data it's trying to process.  In these situations you are much better off calculating any summary or grouped data ahead of time and letting your site query these analytic tables.

Next you'll need to partition the data.  Split those partitions across different drive arrays.  When SQL needs to go to disk it makes it easier to parallelize the reads. (@Simon touched on this).

Basically, the problem boils down to how much data you need to access at any one time.  This is the main problem regardless of the amount of data you have on disk.  Even small databases can be choked if the drives are slow and the amount of available RAM in the DB server isn't enough to keep enough of the DB in memory.

Usually for systems like this large amounts of data are basically inert, meaning that it's rarely accessed.  For example, a PO system might maintain a history of all invoices ever created, but they really only deal with any active ones.

If your system has similar requirements, then you might have a table that is for active records and simply archive them to another table as part of a nightly process.  You could even have statistics like monthly averages (as an example) recomputed as part of that archival.

Just some thoughts.

Comment: My server has only 8GB ram, but that should be enough for basic cache - and I can upgrade pretty easily down the road if needed. Unfortunately, most of the data will need to be constantly and uniformally accessible, however archive tables are still an option. I may end up making an archive table, and dealing with the fact that I'll have to combine the results from two querys whenever I need historical data. As for partitions, I only have one disk array - - five 1TB drives striped with 1TB parity. Is partitioning still useful when you don't have multiple arrays?

Comment: @Giffyguy: I don't see a reason to partition if you can't spread it across multiple physical drives.  After all the read heads can't be in two places at once.  Scratch that, in an array they can be... hmm. You might ask the follow up on serverfault about partitioning sql on the same array.

Answer (score 4):

The only limit is the size of your primary key. Is it an INT or a BIGINT?

SQL will happily store the data without a problem. However, with 100 millions of rows, your best off partitioning the data. There are many good articles on this such as this [article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/partition/64740/).

With partitions, you can have 1 thread per partition working at the same time to parallelise the query even more than is possible without paritioning.

Comment: `INT` gives you 4 billion rows - `BIGINT` quite a bit more :-) - plenty enough for the vast majority of cases, I'd think...

Comment: Partitioning seems to be the general recommendation, althouth I only have one disk array to work with - five 1TB drives striped with 1TB parity.
@mark_s: Actually `INT` gives you roughly 2 billion, since it is signed, but I'm using `BITINT` anyway - no sense in cutting off scalability ...

Answer (score 1):

My gut tells me that you will probably be okay, but you'll have to deal with performance.  It's going to depend on the acceptable time-to-retrieve results from queries.

For your table with the "hundreds of millions of rows", what percentage of the data is accessed regularly?  Is some of the data, rarely accessed?  Do some users access selected data and other users select different data?  You may benefit from data partitioning.